# Footer at the bottom of a page

Tags: html, css, footer

I've looked through multiple answers and for some reason I cannot get any of them to work. I am trying to have the footer of my website placed at the very bottom of the page without any space below it.

[Here is a link to my website.](http://dana.ucc.nau.edu/mds345/) Right now only the index and about page are up.

I am a student, so I know that my code isn't the best, but I'm getting there!

My CSS:

```
html {
height: 100%;}

#wrapper {
position:relative;
background: #fff;
width: 990px;
min-height:100%;
margin: auto;}

footer {
clear: both;
height: 175px;
width: 990px;
background: #005959;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;}
```

And my HTML is a basic wrapper, header, content, footer thing.

Comment: This should help! https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the parent container is acting as the wrapper and essentially has a height of 0.  Thus, when you absolutely position the footer to the bottom, it is positioning to the bottom of that wrapper, which is at the top of the page because it has no height.  You can float your footer and it will show up below.  Try this corrected CSS on your footer:

```
footer {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    height: 175px;
    width: 990px;
    background: #005959;
}
```

EDIT:

If you float all of the interior containers it will force the footer to the bottom:

```
header,
img#slideshow,
section#mainContent,
footer {
     float:left;
     width: 100%;
}
footer {
     height: 175px;
     background: #005959;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped bring the footer towards the bottom of my page, but the wrapper doesn't reach to the bottom of the page despite it having a min-height of 100%. Also, the footer on the about page does not stick to the bottom. I will work on messing with it some more to get it to work.

Comment: Ahh...it will reach the bottom based on the content of the page.  If you need it to stick you would need to fix it to the bottom of the page.  You could use position: fixed, bottom: 0 and it would stay there all the time.  If you want to use absolute positioning you would need to pull your footer outside of the section that is relatively positioned.

Comment: I added an edit...if you float all the internal containers it will push it down as you intend.  Note that you have a bottom padding of 297px on the #mainContent container...that you can probably take off.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your css:

```
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/23/

Comment: This is essentially what I had above and what I worked from, but it still did not seem to work.

Comment: Did you check the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set your `<section>` as an relative so footer will be positioned according to it

Bring footer out of `<section>` tag or remove relative positioning from `section` tag